# Javascript:- OnClick Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php

Hello friends I have a button onclick of that button i am collecting value and passing to php and storing in a php variable **$price_value** and passing in wordpress sql query i am getting result in php but in javascript i am trying to pass **$user_count;**  in javascript like this

```
 var price_final= "<?php echo $user_count ?>";
```

but i am getting undefined

```
//onclick calling function
function price() 
    {
        var price_btn=this.id;
        var price_value = document.getElementById(price_btn).value;
        $.post("premier",
        {
            name: price_value
        },
        function(data, status){
            //alert(data);
        });
        var price_final= "<?php echo $user_count ?>";
        alert(price_final);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "&#8360;&nbsp;"  + price_final;
    }


// premier page 

global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  $price_value = $_POST["name"];

  $result = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT price FROM wp_single WHERE size='".$price_value ."' ", $id);
  $row = $wpdb->get_row($result);
  $user_count = $row->price;
  echo $user_count;
}
```

Comment: You should leann `AJAX` first.. Check value of `data`...

Comment: Please paste your html code involving this?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a technique called AJAX. Here is an example of it working

### Code

Your document called index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ajax(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Hello";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "php_doc.php?name=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onkeyup="ajax(this.value)">
</form>
<p><span id="response"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And then your php_doc.php:

```
<?php

echo "Hello there, " . $GET["name"];
```

### Explanation

In this, when a key is pressed it will send a http request to the php file using GET. You should take a look at article 2.

### References

[Code](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

[HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)